# Error "contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels" when running a (mixed model) regression with factors with 2 or more levels

Tags: r, dplyr, regression, linear-regression, categorical-data

I'm trying to run a simple linear regression model including an outcome (`continuous_outcome`) and two dummy variables for smoking (`current_vs_neversmoking` and `former_vs_neversmoking`). I previously had these two variables combined as just one factor with three levels, but that compares a level to the 2 other levels (i.e. current vs non-current), where I want to specifically compare current vs never and former vs never.

When I try to run the model, I get the error
`` Error in `\contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) :  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels ``.

My data and code look as follows:

```
mydata <- structure(list(pat_id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 
10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 
16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 19, 19, 20, 20, 21, 21, 22, 
22, 22, 22, 22, 23, 23, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 25, 25, 26, 26, 26, 
26, 27, 27, 28, 28, 29, 29, 30, 30, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 32, 32, 
33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 34, 34, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 36, 36, 36, 36, 
36, 37, 37, 38, 38, 39, 39, 40, 40, 41, 41, 42, 42, 43, 43, 44, 
44, 44, 44, 45, 45, 46, 46, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 48, 48, 48, 48, 
48, 49, 49, 50, 50), continuous_outcome = c(0.270481901933073, 
0.306562240871999, 0.586489601087521, 0.663162791491994, 0.696568742621393, 
0.573238528525012, -1.50517834064486, -1.14239124190004, 0.602167001833233, 
0.942169278018825, 0.957507525424839, 0.942401042208738, 1.10173901173947, 
-1.23467796994225, -0.0205580225283486, -0.231308201295527, -0.244470432048288, 
-0.256490437743765, 0.493465625373049, 0.406426360030117, 0.439098160535839, 
0.466158747996811, 0.637429149477194, 0.0219441253328183, 0.102660112718747, 
0.264537705164256, 0.110814584186878, 0.49920541931488, 1.81235625865717, 
1.82870935879674, 0.652695891088804, 0.69291517381055, -0.414081564221917, 
-0.147536404237028, 1.21903849053896, 1.06257819295167, 1.10222362013134, 
1.13246743635661, -0.670943276171988, -0.29653504137582, 0.0590836540990421, 
0.282795470829998, -3.03315551333956, -1.88568994249489, -1.65312212848836, 
-1.13355891646777, -2.20351671143641, -1.45344735861464, -1.25516950174665, 
-0.743390964862038, -0.4629610158192, 0.606862844948187, 0.639058684113426, 
0.609702655264534, 0.633960970096869, 0.548906526787276, 0.108205702176247, 
0.124050755621246, -0.881940114877928, -1.12908469428316, -1.48617053617301, 
-1.45848671123536, 0.0944288383151997, 0.279125369127663, 0.489885538084724, 
0.486578831616853, 0.394325240405338, 0.460090367906543, 0.937968466599025, 
-1.20642488217955, -0.981185479943044, 0.570576924035185, 0.532219882463515, 
0.620627645616656, 0.631553233135331, 0.874526189757774, -0.194145530051932, 
-0.0979606735363465, 0.565800797611727, 0.509862625778819, 0.5741604159953, 
0.519945775026426, 0.387595824059598, 0.395925960524675, -1.74473193173614, 
-0.848779543387106, 1.41774732048115, 1.51159850388708, 0.462882007460068, 
0.483950525664105, -0.366500414469296, -0.0920163339687414, -0.166351980885457, 
-0.0860682256869157, -0.219608109715091, 0.195934077939654, 0.356018784590499, 
0.484056029455595, 0.57498034210306, 0.572359796530477, 0.599809068756398, 
0.542583937381158, 0.698337291640914, 0.740921504459827, 0.45772616988788, 
0.405098691997856, 0.485871287409578, 0.442621726153633, 0.29123670436699, 
0.0303617893266618, 0.00448603635822562, -0.0619887479801569, 
0.003984369355659, -0.140521412371098, -0.971697227999586, -1.20190205773194, 
-1.53965813080136, -1.30849790890586, 1.58558160520627, 1.61870389553583, 
-5.84164915563387, -5.84164915563387, 0.777919475931911, 0.972720285314287, 
0.477725719575478, 0.461105062597019, 0.616300922435037, 0.528825235299615, 
0.752152176797313, 0.915416601798041, 0.906483121528581, 0.868345778494055, 
-2.885534489146, -1.64736196365156, -0.768874512446897, -0.66979572486731, 
0.73917509257953, 0.883831498985817, 0.884240158759821, 0.916187794016791, 
1.38773159469184, -0.00127946509641595, 0.302272238178157, 0.340088450861561, 
0.295163832020064, 0.94639364965826, 0.839369926698037, 0.913777832307086, 
0.767222595331384, 0.898887351534535), current_vs_neversmoking = structure(c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 
2L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("Never smoker", "Current smoker"
), class = "factor"), former_vs_neversmoking = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
NA, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Never smoker", "Former smoker"
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 150L), class = "data.frame")

summary(mydata)
     pat_id      continuous_outcome   current_vs_neversmoking   former_vs_neversmoking
 Min.   : 1.00   Min.   :-5.8416    Never smoker  :25         Never smoker :25        
 1st Qu.:11.25   1st Qu.:-0.2132    Current smoker:28         Former smoker:97        
 Median :24.00   Median : 0.4409    NA's          :97         NA's         :28        
 Mean   :24.60   Mean   : 0.0737                                                      
 3rd Qu.:36.00   3rd Qu.: 0.6493                                                      
 Max.   :50.00   Max.   : 1.8287                                                      

model_1 <- lm(formula=continuous_outcome ~ current_vs_neversmoking + former_vs_neversmoking, 
              data=mydata, 
              na.action="na.omit")

Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

Why do I get this error? Both categorical variables are coded as factors and have 2 levels...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have coded your factors wrong.

```
> table(mydata$current_vs_neversmoking, mydata$former_vs_neversmoking)

                 Never smoker Former smoker
  Never smoker             25             0
  Current smoker            0             0
```

Shows that the only rows woth non_na values are the ones where both `current_vs_neversmoking == 'Never smoker'` and '`ormer_vs_neversmoking == 'Never smoker'`'. Note that you throw away everything with NA's when estimating your model.

I believe you want to include your smoking variables in a single factor but recode it so that the never smoker is the baseline.

```
mydata$smoker <- ifelse(is.na(mydata$current_vs_neversmoking), as.character(mydata$former_vs_neversmoking), as.character(mydata$current_vs_neversmoking))
mydata$smoker <- factor(mydata$smoker, levels=c("Never smoker", "Current smoker",  "Former smoker"))
```

Now:

```
summary(model_1 <- lm(formula=continuous_outcome ~ smoker, 
              data=mydata, 
              na.action="na.omit"))
Call:
lm(formula = continuous_outcome ~ smoker, data = mydata, na.action = "na.omit")

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max
-5.8724 -0.2720  0.2926  0.5526  1.7979

Coefficients:
                     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)           -0.4049     0.2161  -1.874 0.062948 .
smokerCurrent smoker   1.0545     0.2973   3.547 0.000523 ***
smokerFormer smoker    0.4356     0.2423   1.798 0.074257 .
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.08 on 147 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.08135,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.06885
F-statistic: 6.509 on 2 and 147 DF,  p-value: 0.001957
```

Now current and former smokers are compared to the baseline of never-smokers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But aren't current and former smoking contrasted with non-current and non-smoking in the linear model you've proposed (and never vs. non-never is not included bc it is the reference)? Seeing as, if what you're saying is true (namely that it's both versus never) wouldn't that be the same as what I'm doing with the dummy variables?
I think I don't completely understand how r computes the contrasts for the linear model then, as

Comment: As in, I want to contrast current versus never and former versus never. Not current versus non-current and former versus non-former.

Comment: You have three mutually exclusive categories: never, current and former. In my model above, the constant is the average in the never group, and the coefficients for former and current are the differences between never, and former and current respectively. This is what is known as "dummy coding"  in this tutorial: https://marissabarlaz.github.io/portfolio/contrastcoding/

Comment: "As in, I want to contrast current versus never and former versus never. " <- this is exactly what I do in my answer.