# in r, how to deal with 'contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels' when my variables in the model have 2 levels?

Tags: r

I am trying to do an lm() in R, my outcome is continuous and my variables after the '~' are factors and have levels 0 and 1. Yest when running lm( ) I am getting the 'contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels' error.

I have tried dummy coding them, still get the same error. I also got the summary after lm( ) '1 not defined because of singularities' which produced NA in the summary for one of the variables I am trying to get to work in lm( ).

I also tried using [Error "contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels" when running a (mixed model) regression with factors with 2 or more levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70377786/error-contrasts-can-be-applied-only-to-factors-with-2-or-more-levels-when-runn) in the answer: `mydata$smoker <- factor(mydata$smoker, levels=c("Never smoker", "Current smoker",  "Former smoker"))` and also got the error in the title.

I am new to R, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my mistake. What happened was that I was entering my `lm()` incorrectly so it was only accepting one independent variable rather than multiple. Additionally, if for instance you have `example <- lm(test_score ~ study_type, univ_title, data = df`, it will do the analyses using the subset of the data which in this case is univ_title. After changing `study_type, univ_title` to `study_type + univ_title` the `lm()` got fixed.